# SQL to Linq : Group by id but can't sum values

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am searching for equivalent to this query:

```
SELECT Prd.barcode , SumQUA = SUM(AType.unit*MIA.quantity) 
FROM [dbo].[MerchantInventoryActivity] AS MIA
JOIN [dbo].[MerchantInventoryActivityType] AS AType ON (MIA.typeId = AType.id)
JOIN [dbo].[Product] AS Prd ON (MIA.productId = Prd.id)
WHERE MIA.invoiceId =  '123'   
GROUP BY Prd.barcode
```

i got stuck at the SumQUA = SUM(AType.unit*MIA.quantity) . Here's what I got so far:

```
(from mia in Entities.MerchantInventoryActivity
join Prd in Entities.Product on mia.productId equals Prd.id
join AType in Entities.MerchantInventoryActivityType on mia.typeId equals AType.id
where mia.invoiceId == invoiceId
group Prd by Prd.barcode into g    
select new 
{
   Barcode = g.Key,
   SumQUA = // ??
}).ToList();
```

Thank you!

Comment: Uh, doesn't Atype.unit * mia.quantity work? Or what's the problem?

Comment: it is generally thought to be a bad idea to use joins with `LINQ`. See [this](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can project first to anonymous type and then group:

```
(from mia in Entities.MerchantInventoryActivity
    join Prd in Entities.Product on mia.productId equals Prd.id
    join AType in Entities.MerchantInventoryActivityType on mia.typeId equals AType.id
    where mia.invoiceId == invoiceId
    select new { Prd.barcode, AType.unit, MIA.quantity } into temp
    group temp by temp.barcode into g
    select new
    {
        Barcode = g.Key,
        SumQUA = g.Sum(c => c.unit * c.quantity)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add check for null when sum

```
(from mia in Entities.MerchantInventoryActivity
        join Prd in Entities.Product on mia.productId equals Prd.id
        join AType in Entities.MerchantInventoryActivityType on mia.typeId equals AType.id
        where mia.invoiceId == invoiceId
        select new { Prd.barcode, AType.unit, MIA.quantity } into temp
        group temp by temp.barcode into g
        select new
        {
            Barcode = g.Key,
            SumQUA = g.Sum(c => c.unit??0 * c.quantity??0)
        });
```